# how change the select2 css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys i have select2 in modal when i apply the select 2 `class="form-control"` doesn't work [image]

I want to change the select like the other input here's my code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<form method="post" id="ajouterPoduitSortie">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
    </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter un produit</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div>
        <label for="ref">Réference:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="refe" id="refe">
        <br>
        <label for="nomp">Nom de produit:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nompr" id="nompr">
        <br>            
        <label for="mrqu">Marque:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mrqa" id="mrqa">
        <br>            
        <label>Nom Catégorie:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="nomcat" name="nomcat">
          <option value=""></option>
          {% for valeur in nomc %}                                                  
           <option value="{{valeur.codecateg}}" name="categorie">{{ valeur.nomcat }}</option>
      {% endfor %} 
      </select>
      <br>          
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="validationFormButton"> Valider</button>
        <button value="" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

and this is js of select2

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#nomcat").select2();   }
```

as you can see in picture the select2 become small i want to be same large of input , thank you

Comment: What have you tried? You could try setting its width to 100%.

Comment: Have you tried styling the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to target:

```
.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

or

```
.select2 {
 width: 100% !important;
}
```