# How to change border of select2 DDL or text color of selected value based on the forced selected value on load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a select2 DDL, I bind the data using code behind and force a value to be added and selected. in addition to the list I bind to the select2 control

I tried changing the color of the forced selected value using code behind but with no luck.

I am trying to use javascript to check if the value exists using a hidden field and trying to either change the text color of the selected value or change the border of the dropdown to indicate to the users that a value was added to the select data list.

This can be accomplished with an ASO:DLL or HTML `select` control.
any help is appreciated

```
 <script>                            
                          $('#<%=TestDLL.ClientID%>').select2();
                          //$('select').select2();
                         
                         var dll = ('#<%=TestDLL.SelectedValue%>');
                              
                          var hiddenfield = ('#<%=HiddenFieldbod.Value%>');

                          console.log(dll, hiddenfield,);

                          if (dll == hiddenfield) {
                              $('#TestDLL').css("color", "red");
                              $('#<%=TestDLL.ClientID%>').select2({
                                  selectionCssClass: 'select2- my-class-section'
                              });
                              
                          }

                              </sript>
```

CSS added to select2.min.css

```
.select2- my-class-section {
border-color: #FF0000;
```

}

Comment: added some code I tried to help in finding a recommendation or solution

Answer (score 0):

Target the container of the select2. See a previous answer I gave:

[how change the select2 css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250066/how-change-the-select2-css/46250444#46250444)

Comment: thanks for the reply, how to target the select container to force the border to be red when a selected value matches the criteria?